# Consider $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,\ldots,N\}$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{*} $where $a \neq b$, do $ar $ and $br$ belong to same set??

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,\ldots,N\}$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{*} $where  $a \neq b$, is there any condition for $p,a,b$ and $N$ 
so that

- $ar \mod p$

and

- $br \mod p$

belong to same set( group)??

I want to prove that. But I have not any background of group theory.

Comment: $ar$, reduced modulo $p$, is an element of ${\bf Z}_p$, and so is $br$, reduced modulo $p$. It's not clear what you mean when you ask whether they belong to the same set.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just want to know that given $ar \mod p$ and $br \mod p$ whether it is possible to identify $a$ and $b$ without knowing $r$

Comment: If you don't know $r$, then $ar=(2a)(r/2)$ and $br=(2b)(r/2)$, so you can't distinguish $a$ and $b$ from $2a$ and $2b$ (I'm assuming $p$ is meant to be odd, so $r/2$ makes sense).